# How to pad an image aligned with text in Rmd document

Tags: html, css, r-markdown, knitr

In an Rmarkdown document, for output either as `github_document` or `html_document`, I have a set of
package icons that I want to align with the package description, with some padding around the icon.

I'm currently getting this result.  I want to add some extra space around the icon.

[image]

This is what I've tried, but neither the `style="padding:'20px'"` in `<img>` nor the `style="margin-left: 25px;"` in `<p>`
works. Note that the icon is correctly positioned using `align='left'`.

```
### heplots

[<img src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/friendly/heplots/master/man/figures/logo.png' height='120' align='left' 
      style="padding:'20px'">](https://github.com/friendly/heplots)

<p style="margin-left: 25px;">
Provides HE plot and other functions for visualizing hypothesis
    tests in multivariate linear models. HE plots represent sums-of-squares-and-products 
    matrices for linear hypotheses and for error using ellipses (in two
    dimensions) and ellipsoids (in three dimensions). The related 'candisc' package
    provides visualizations in a reduced-rank canonical discriminant space when
    there are more than a few response variables.
</p>
```

The result will have a collection of such package descriptions. I suppose I could try to format this as a table, but that would add a lot of extra overhead. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem (bug?) with the RStudio rendering.

When I render this to a `github_document` and view the resulting `.md` file on Github, the padding around the images seems OK.